# How to reset row names?

Tags: r

Here is a sample data set:

```
sample1 <- data.frame(Names=letters[1:10], Values=sample(seq(0.1,1,0.1)))
```

When I'm reordering the data set, I'm losing the row names order

```
sample1[order(sample1$Values), ]
    Names Values
 7      g    0.1
 4      d    0.2
 3      c    0.3
 9      i    0.4
10      j    0.5
 5      e    0.6
 8      h    0.7
 6      f    0.8
 1      a    0.9
 2      b    1.0
```

Desired output:

```
    Names Values
 1      g    0.1
 2      d    0.2
 3      c    0.3
 4      i    0.4
 5      j    0.5
 6      e    0.6
 7      h    0.7
 8      f    0.8
 9      a    0.9
10      b    1.0
```

Comment: Just use `row.names(Ordersample2) <- NULL`

Comment: What `sample1` has to do with anything here?

Comment: Also, do you *really* need the row names? Are you using them in any way?

Comment: Since it has two downvotes, would be admin so kind and delete this question?

Comment: @David. I referred `sample1` as the data generated for the first chunk of data and sample2 to the second. I don't think it was entirely wrong.

Comment: You only operated on `sample2`, how `sample1` related to the desired output? Also, what is your question? How to rename the row names or how to order? Because your title mentions order rather row names. Lastly, are you really using these row names? It usually better to some column instead (this is why `data.table` don't have row names for example).

Comment: The sample2 has `Values=sample(seq(0.1,1,0.1))` this part! Or is that same as Values=seq(0.1,1,0.1)? ALso, believe or not, I didn't know that it concerns row names. Since I know now :) I can reformulate the question. But I wish to be closed now. Thanks

Comment: `sample` is a function, while `sample1` is a data frame. When you do `sample(seq(0.1,1,0.1))` it has nothing to do with `sample1` dat set

Comment: good, I meant to reshuffle the order of seq(0.1,1,0.1), I didn't reference that to sample2 or sample1. I know it is a function as you can see.

Comment: Nevermind, I've rewrote your question and converted from downvote to upvote.

Comment: `dplyr` doesn't keep rownames, so `sample1 %>% arrange(Values)`

Comment: @Khashaa That's probably because it uses `data.table` underneath

Comment: @David. Actually this question is related to this question of mine (I thought the rownames is at fault but isn't): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961106/treemap-color-range-with-r

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try

```
rownames(Ordersample2) <- 1:10
```

or more generally

```
rownames(Ordersample2) <- NULL
```

Comment: I would use `rownames(Ordersample2) <- NULL` or `1:nrow(Ordersample2)` to be a bit more general.

Answer (score 6):

I had a dplyr usecase:

```
df %>% as.data.frame(row.names = 1:nrow(.))
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional dplyr use case, especially useful when transposing a dataframe and needing the rownames as a column before resetting the index:

```
df <- df %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
mutate(parameter = rownames(.)) %>% 
`rownames<-`(NULL)
```